# Transpose and concatenate R data.tables

Tags: r, data.table, concatenation

This is a simple task in R, but it appears that there is a misunderstanding on my part. Any help clarifying is appreciated:

I have the following R data.table of a single text file:

```
dat = as.data.table(fread(...))

      type         proportion                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
  1:  type_3      0.5570502431                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
  2:  type_5      0.1108589951                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
  3:  type_1      0.0688816856                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
  4:  type_9      0.0601296596                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
  5:  type_8      0.0554294976                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
  6:  type_12     0.0450567261                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
  7:  type_2      0.0322528363                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
  8:  type_4      0.0202593193                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
  9:  type_7      0.0166936791                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
 10:  type_6      0.0145867099                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
 11:  type_10     0.0141004862                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
 12:  type_11     0.0040518639
```

There are approx. 500 of these text files, each of which I can read in as an R `data.table` and put into an R list. This is quite simple in principle:

```
list_of_data.tables = list(dat1, dat2, dat3, ...)

concat = do.call("rbind", list_of_data.tables)
```

This isn't the format I would like though. I would like to take the column `type` as the header of the final concatenated data.table, `type_1`, `type_2`, `type_3`, etc. Then, each row of the final concatenated data.table would be the column `porportion` for `dat1`, etc.

Here is the format of the final concatenated data.table:

```
     type_1 type_2 type_3 type_4 type_5 type_6 ...
dat1 0.557  0.110  0.068  0.0601 0.0554 0.045  ...
dat2 0.23   0.324  0.12   0.0723 0.002  0.004  ...
...
```

My first thought would be to transpose the original data.table with `t()`, but this doesn't make `type` the header. Furthermore, I am not sure how to label each row by `dat1`, etc.

What is the correct way to do such a simple thing?

Comment: Side note: `?fread` explains that it returns a data.table, no need to coerce. Also, `?rbind` explains that you can use `rbindlist` instead of `do.call`ing it.

Comment: Thank you for this, I didn't know this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each `dat` you need to `spread` the data

```
library(tidyr)
new.dat <- dat %>%
             spread(type, proportion)
```

Then for your `list_of_new.dat`, assuming they are in a list, you can bind them with

```
Reduce("full_join", list_of_new.dat)
```

Comment: `tidyr`...I was originally thinking of using `map` verbs as well, but since I didn't, you can use `tidyr` only. I've edited my answer. But I'm not sure where `%>%` comes from...maybe `dplyr`?

Comment: I think I would have to create a new column for each `dat1`, `dat2`, etc.

Comment: Labeling each row by which `data.table` it comes from in the R list, i.e. `dat1`, `dat2`, etc. 
Otherwise, it works!

Comment: As long as you make your list in order, `dat1-N`, then `Reduce` will keep the same order...you can then use `rownames(desired) <- c("dat1"...`. Does that work?

Comment: What is the difference between `Reduce("full_join", list)` and `do.call("rbind", list)`?

Comment: Nothing really. `Reduce` might be faster than `do.call("rbind"`, but they should give you the same output.